# What does the ECT button on a 94 Camry do?

Tags: toyota, camry

On a Toyota Camry XLE sedan, V6, there is a button labeled "ECT".   What does it do?

Comment: Your question is difficult to follow. Your title says one thing then the body of the question talks about Ford and Toyota and the cars options. Please take a minute to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly a duplicate of this question [What is ECT Mode for? - Toyota Cars?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1962/what-is-ect-mode-for-toyota-cars)

The ECT is the Electronic Controlled Transmission button. Engaging the ECT system adjusts rpm at which the transmission will shift. When engaged, the engine will reach higher rpms than it normally would before the transmission shifts. The purpose of this is to keep the engine closer to its power band while running through the gears.

Typically the ECT is engaged when extra power is desired for quick acceleration (like merging onto the interstate). You shouldn't drive with the ECT engaged all of the time though because it negatively affects fuel efficiency in the engine.

Answer (score 3):

The ECT stands for Electronically Controlled Transmission.
The button when pushed should change the shift points on your transmission.
In one mode it can make the car shift sooner for better fuel economy, in the other mode it can make the car shift later for more power/acceleration